# Vim-Latex (Latex-Suite) closes vim instance after compilation

Tags: biber, vim, vim-latex

When I create/change some labels, and recompile with \ll, the vim instance of my .tex document closes unexpectedly. I do nothing else. When using

```
let g:Tex_MultipleCompileFormats = 'pdf'
```

in my .vimrc then I return to my open .tex file, but I get the error message "Empty bibliography on input line xxx".

I am using Biber as my bibtex backend.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Does `let g:Tex_BibtexFlavor='biber'` do the job?  By default vim uses `bibtex` in its full compilation rule and needs to be explicitly told to do otherwise.  Otherwise can you compile a basic tex file which doesn't use bibtex or load additional packages?

Comment: @DaiBowen wow, thank you! Didn't think it would be such an easy fix!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was solved in the comments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding `let g:Tex_BibtexFlavor='biber'` to my .vimrc did the trick, as suggested by Dai Bowen.